# Re-order mongoose object (instance) to have same order like the related mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodeJs with express to make a web application and using mongoose for creating models in my application. As you know in Javascript we cannot guarantee the ordering of a JS Object.
Right now when I use find() or findOne() method to make a query of a specific model, It returns a JS Object and all thing work great and as I expected. The problem is that I need the returned JS object to has the same ordering I defined in related mongoose model.
Consider My User Model Definition in /models/user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var user = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    email: String,
    password: String
  },
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['admin', 'customer', 'guest']
  },
  address: {
    country: String,
    state: String,
    rest: String
  },
  phoneNumber: String,
  isActive: Boolean,
  registeredDate: String
});
```

Now if I use find method to find a user with for example a specific email address(which already exists in DB), it returns correct one with no problem, but returned object does not have the exact order as defined in above js mongoose model(which is expected from JS objects). In short I need the returned object to be like below (What I need in my app):

```
{
  local: {
    email: 'someone@example.com',
    password: '123dfgREW'
  },
  firstName: 'Rose',
  lastName: 'Marent',
  role: 'customer',
  address: {
    country: 'Brazil',
    state: 'etc',
    rest: 'etc'
  },
  phoneNumber: '+654987321',
  isActive: true,
  registeredDate: '2/19/2006'
}
```

But It is Like below (What I Got):

```
{
  isActive: true,
  role: 'customer',
  address: {
    state: 'etc',
    country: 'Brazil',
    rest: 'etc'
  },
  phoneNumber: '+654987321',
  lastName: 'Marent',
  registeredDate: '2/19/2006'
  firstName: 'Rose',
  local: {
    email: 'someone@example.com',
    password: '123dfgREW'
  },
}
```

How can I re-order the got object to have order same as defined Schema for that Model using mongoose?